# Enviar Imagem com Socket Java

Tags: java, imagem, socket

Estou precisando fazer um programinha capaz de enviar uma imagem para um servidor (meu pc para teste) ao pressionar um botão, já sei como selecionar o arquivo, mas não consigo achar/entender nada na internet que me ajude no envio. Alguém sabe, ou tem um exemplo de um método simples que me ajude?

Comment: Precisa ser com socket? ou pode utilizar um servidor web para receber o arquivo?

Comment: Socket, a não ser q seja algo muito díficil/complicado, dai pode ser usado um meio alternativos.

Comment: Vou usar esta documentação para dar a resposta: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html; claro que tudo fica mais fácil tratar caso você use rode sobre servlets, faça requisições HTTP de envio de dados, mas vou focar aqui em socket puro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando socket puro e cru, essa questão trata de 4 pontos:

1. leitura de arquivo
2. escrita em socket
3. abertura de server socket
4. leitura de um server socket

> **NOTA**: por questões de simplicidade e brevidade não estou usando *buffered streams*; não faça isso em código de produção sem saber muito bem que você deseja não usar as *buffered streams*, pois elas normalmente ajudam e muito na performance das operações de leitura e escrita.

### Leitura de arquivo

Para começar, precisamos de um caminho. Vou chamar de `path`, assumir que é uma variável que será corretamente preenchida. Para abrir o arquivo para leitura, usamos o [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html). Para ler os primeiros 255 bytes de um arquivo, podemos fazer assim:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);

byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
int readBytes = in.read(buffer);
in.close();
```

Para não esquecer de fechar o recurso, podemos usar do *AutoCloseable* e por num [`try-with-recources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path)) {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
    int readBytes = in.read(buffer);
}
```

### Escrita em socket

Para escrever no socket, precisamos abrir um socket e pegar sua `OutpuStream`. Para abrir o socket, pegar a stream e escrever "uma string qualquer", podemos fazer assim ([documentação](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)):

```
try (
    Socket bareSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
    OutputStream out = bareSocket.getOutputStream();
) {
    out.write("uma string qualquer".getBytes());
}
```

Note que é sempre necessário fechar tudo, por isso que pus tudo num bloco `try-with-resources`.

Então, com o `OutputStream` aberto, precisamos escrever tudo que é lido do `InputStream` do arquivo para o `OutputStream` do socket. O pessoal do Apache já resolveu esse problema para a gente com o [`IOUtils.copy`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)). Então, a escrita no socket com o conteúdo do arquivo ficaria assim:

```
try (
    Socket bareSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
    OutputStream out = bareSocket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path)
) {
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
}
```

### Abertura de server socket

A própria Oracle disponibiliza um exemplo de código usando `ServerSocket`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/EchoServer.java

Não há segredos aqui, basta criar um objeto `ServerSocket` usando uma porta e, quando ele receber uma chamada de conexão, pegar o socket gerado com `accept()`. Algo mais ou menos assim, para um `portNumber` informado:

```
try (
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    ) {
    // abri a conexão, agora faça coisas...
}
```

### Leitura de um server socket

Como já temos a `InputStream`, podemos usá-la normalmente como outra `InputStream` qualquer. Por exemplo, se quisermos escrever a imagem para o arquivo no caminho `pathDestino`, fazemos assim:

```
try (
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pathDestino, false);
    ) {
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
}
```