# Conectar aplicativo android a um software instalado no pc para transferir arquivo

Tags: android, lazarus

Vou iniciar o desenvolvendo de um software em lazarus e um aplicativo para android. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma biblioteca ou alguma referência para fazer a comunicação via usb entre o software e o aplicativo. Vou precisar transferir arquivo (.sql) do aplicativo para atualizar o banco de dados do software instalado no pc.

Vou implementar um botão no software para quando for acionado reconhecer o aplicativo e assim transferir os dados.

Estou pesquisando sobre isso na internet mas não consegui encontrar nenhuma referência que norteie nesse sentido. Alguém sabe onde posso encontrar uma referência para fazer isso?

Comment: Poderia fazer via bluetooth ou via HTTP só que comunicação local via rede local. Mais fácil que implementar uma funcionalidade toda USB que provavelmente precisaria fazer root no android para conseguir pegar o arquivo de dentro do dispositivo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, ficaria complicado mesmo com uma pasta pública dentro do dispositivo móvel?

Comment: creio não, mas não posso afirmar, a parte complicada seria configurar a PORTA USB (numeração) e algum tipo de auto-detecção.

Comment: Talvez ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217986/64969

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, eu trabalho com um App e um Software que se comunicam por arquivos, por sinal o Software é em Delphi rsrsrs, a troca de informação funciona assim, enviamos os arquivos para a uma caixa de email e o outro disposivito faz essa leitura baixa o arquivo .sql e faz essa importação, você poderia implementar isso em FTP caso ache mais viável. Ou até mesmo por WebService e caso não queira algo na Web pode fazer uma funcionalidade do App conseguir acessar um servidor na sua rede local e colocar lá os arquivos ou vice versa e o outro software fazer a leitura do mesmo. Caso ainda necessite e se não fui claro, me avisa que poderei te ajudar.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta. Interessante as opções que você apresentou, mas estou querendo algo mais simples, se existir como é claro, pois o usuário que vai instalar o software no pc não vai ter conhecimento suficiente para configurar o FTP ou o webservice no pc dele. Por isso estou querendo algo mais simples, por exemplo após o sistema instalado no pc o usuário possa plugar o celular no pc via usb e fazer uma busca com o software para obter o caminho da pasta pública no celular e assim transferir o arquivo. Será que é possível fazer desta forma?

Comment: Olá, Acho pouco provável que funcione assim, pois ao conectar um celular com Android a um PC ele não gera aquelas unidade (D:, G:) ele abre agora como um dispositivo e disponibiliza somente dentro dele o acesso a memória interna ou cartão SD. Outra alternativa seria quando o Software fosse instaladao no PC ele criar tipo um servidor com um nome fixo predefinido no App para o App achar esse PC e mandar os arquivos.